# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when using UIPageControl in navigation bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uipagecontrol

When i first click on the UITabBarItem "Tabeller" this view is presented:

[image]

And after selecting any of the rows this view is presented:

[image]

What i am trying to achieve is to display the PageControl in the Navigationbar. It works and all BUT i am getting a weird crash in this scenario:

1) i click on the UITabBarItem "Tabeller"

2) Choose any row

3) PageControl is presented, i swipe right left (this part dont matter)

4) I switch to another UITabBarItem

5) Switch BACK to "Tabeller"

6) The application crashes

[image]

I do not know where this crash is happening. Tried putting some breakpoints in viewDidLoad for the first view when "Tabeller" is clicked but nothing happened.

Something to note is that this started happening after i implemented the code to show the PageControl, this is the code i used in the datasource delegate:

```
self.navigationController.delegate = self;
CGSize navBarSize = self.navigationController.navigationBar.bounds.size;
CGPoint origin = CGPointMake( navBarSize.width/2, navBarSize.height/2 );
self.pageControl = [[UIPageControl alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(origin.x, origin.y+16,
                                                                   0, 0)]; //Here added 45 to Y and it did the trick


self.pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = navbarColor;
self.pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];

[self.pageControl setNumberOfPages:2];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:self.pageControl];
```

If you need additional information please let me know and i will update the question. Thanks!

Comment: Add Exception break point to find the crash ....

Comment: I just added it "All Execeptions" came up and i tried running the simulator again but did not get the exact line where the crash happened? @ChandanSingh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to access a deallocated object. Try enabling zombie objects:

- Edit your Target Scheme
- Select 'Run' on the left menu
- Check the checkbox 'Enable Zombie Objects'

[image: screenshot edit scheme]

This will not release any objects, so make sure to disable it after debugging.